# Radio button selection default not working after disablement

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, refresh

I have some radio buttons. The fist one is selected by default.

I need to disable them when processing some data.

Issue: When re-enabling them, the first one is not selected anymore, ie. none selected!

```
<RadioButton GroupName="ShowSelector" Content="For Selected" 
   IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowForSelected, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=True}" 
   IsEnabled="{Binding NotUnderProcessing}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="ShowSelector" Content="For All" 
   IsEnabled="{Binding NotUnderProcessing}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a ViewModel behind your View. When you process your data you have to set the NotUnderProcessing Property and bind your WrapPanel like this:

```
<RadioButton IsEnabled="{Binding NotUnderProcessing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And your ShowForSelected Property might also have the UpdateSourceTrigger in the IsChecked expression.

Edit: When I tried this I run into trouble, I fixed this by making the processing to a Task. Because the ProcessingValue was not setted. And in addition to that I added a Second Property for the second RadioButton and now it's working.

Comment: I have tested what you recommended , didn't fix the issue. Sorry seems my questions was not clear though. It is not about the NotUnderProcessing property not bound/called, its about the buttons default check that vanishes. I've updated the question and code, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @goul: are you implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?